# Unexpected result for two updates in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

```
    with
    u1 as (
        update todel set val=val+1 where id='key' returning *
    ),
    u2 as (
        update todel set val=val+2 where id='key' returning *
    )
    select * from u1
    union all
    select * from u2
    ;
```

Expected result is two rows, but I get one,

```
     id  | val
    -----+-----
     key |  11
```

Why is that so, what am I missing? Server is pg 9.6.6

Comment: yes, and `union all` doesn't remove duplicates.

Comment: you are doing update in id = key in 2 CTE's but update will happen on single row . I think it will not hold it as 2 rows @Сухой27

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that the second CTE does not see the changes made by the first.

Comment: Also it looks like second CTE returns empty set, which is unexpected (for me).

Comment: Do I need some explicit transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable.

The result is like only one of them was executed.

Comment: Yes, the second one was skipped/ignored, but that part doesn't look documented by pg. So result should be two rows which were result of updates on the same snapshot.

Comment: I agree, they should write clearly that one of the queries may be ignored.